# Scanner and interpolation

Tags: resolution, scanning

I am using an Epson Perfection V370 scanner to scan handwritten documents. Epson says that the scanner has a maximum optical resolution of 4800 dpi.

Now I understand that this is achieved without using any interpolation, just the data that the scanner sensor can capture. However when I preview an A4 size sheet of paper with some notes on it using the Epson scanner software, highlight which part of the sheet I want scanned and then scan it at 4800 dpi, instead of getting more detail when I zoom in, the image just becomes blurry.

This is how the image looks before I zoom to the full resolution:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I zoom in 100%.

[image]

As you can see there is no more detail once you zoom in. Is this a result of interpolation or just the fact that the scanner sensor can't capture more detail?

To be clear, I want to capture as much data as possible, but since interpolation just gives me useless data and uses more space, I want to scan the images at the highest resolution I can, without using interpolation.

Comment: Can you add a sample scanned image so people can see what you are referring to?  Just a general comment--4800 dpi is way beyond a useful resolution for something like handwriting because the features you're trying to capture are much larger.  You end up with mainly artifacts (noise), rather than relevant content.  Similarly, if you scan a photograph at that resolution, you would see the texture of the paper, and grains in the emulsion in between giant specs of dust rather than the picture, which would be an indistinct blur.

Comment: fixer1234 is absolutely correct on this. The only thing I would even consider scanning at such a high resolution might be a slide of Kodachrome 25, which (I believe) had a resolution of just north of 150 dots per mm.  So for a 24 x 36 mm slide, that would be just over 3600 dots per inch.  I can't think of anything that would benefit from being scanned at 4800 dpi.

Comment: Does this mean that the scanner is incapable of capturing more detail, or the paper with the writing doesn't more of it? I want to use the full capability of my scanner and I am willing to scan even the paper fiber, as long as it's not blurry like I described.

Comment: @NeilL: FYI, comments need to be addressed like this one or nobody will be aware of your posting.  The only way to get a good answer is to add an image, or a link to one, so people can understand exactly what you're referring to as "blurry".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the V37 scanner, which is the same as yours except it lacks the transparency adapter.  Your question aroused my curiosity and led to a number of interesting findings.

The few times I had previously ventured into 4800 dpi was for microscopic analysis using a previous scanner.  That experience was tack-sharp results.  My V30 had been used only for "normal" scanning, and it does a great job at that.  4800 dpi, not so much; sadly, not in the same league as my previous one.  Resolution that high is intended primarily for scanning 35 mm slides.  I suspect it will suck at that.

**Settings**

A little bit of what you're seeing relates to the automated settings.  It looks like you set it on "photo".  At 4800 dpi, you're scanning a "photo" of ink-stained paper fibers, so the color is either close to white or very dark.  That doesn't give the software much to work with to come up with optimization settings.  This was my result scanning the word "Test" written in blue ink on white paper (this is the tip of the "S" and part of the "T"; the results were worse than yours):

[image: Sample 1]

Next, I tried some inkjet-printed text, and manually optimized the settings:

[image: Sample 2]

The row of colored dots across the top is a thin ruled line.  Part of what makes the characters fuzzy is discolored haze, especially above and below the print lines.

To try to control for some of the variables, I scanned a magazine cover; high quality printing on glossy paper (actual size of the image):

[image: photo normal size]

View at 4800 dpi:

[image: photo 4800]

What you're looking at in the middle is a tooth.  The dots are how color photos are printed in magazines.  Their edges are blurry in the scan.

**Linux vs. Windows**

All of this was done in Linux, using the Linux scan driver.  I did a final test in Windows, using Epson's Windows software:

[image: photo Windows]

The dots are much more distinct and the color optimization is also better.  It's still nothing to write home about, but the improvement is surprising.  In this one, you can see some fine horizontal lines in some of the colors.  It appears to be the scan lines.  These are more visible in the Linux scan after extreme sharpening:

[image: Linux photo sharp]

It's possible that the scanner really isn't up to the task of 4800 dpi scanning, and the images are left a bit blurry to smooth out the scan lines.  Here is the original writing ("e" in the word "test"), scanned in Windows:

[image: Windows writing scan]

It is substantially better than the Linux scan, but if you look closely, the fuzziness on the edges are the scan lines.

**Bottom line:** Your best 4800 dpi results will be from scanning in Windows using Epson's software.  However, it looks like the scanner really isn't capable of providing tack-sharp results at that resolution.

Comment: Since the printer apparently can't capture more, does this mean that when you scan at 4800 dpi, it just uses interpolation to bump the resolution up? If so, then is there a way to determine at which point, the scanner stops capturing 'real-world detail' and kicks in the interpolation?

Comment: According to the specs, the optical resolution is 4800 dpi.  What you're seeing is not interpolated.  The scanner just doesn't do a great job at it.  I tried a few different resolution settings, and as I backed off from 4800, the quality improved.  It will really come down to what you're satisfied with.  I'd be curious what kind of results you get with a 35 mm slide.

Comment: And when I scan an image at 4800 dpi, does the output image, despite being blurry as I described, still contain some more 'real data' than say an image scanned at 3200 dpi?

Comment: It is real data. The question is whether it is useful data.  Take it to an absurd extreme. Suppose the scanner's resolution was close to infinite, and you could produce a perfect scan showing the molecules of the ink and paper. If my ballpark calculations are right, the ink line would be around 250,000 pixels across. A large image file might contain 1/50 of the width of an ink line. That wouldn't serve any useful purpose in relation to the handwriting. If your objective is to do something with the handwriting, the detail at 4800 dpi isn't useful and just complicates using typical image tools.